# Doctrine ORM HYDRATE_SCALAR vs HYDRATE_ARRAY

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to get all values of a column from a table through Doctrine ORM using following query:

```
SELECT item.templateId FROM MyBundle:Item item WHERE item.id IN (:ids)
```

I know Doctrine has hydration mode `Query::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR` which returns single scalar value. When, however, having more than one record in result it throws `NonUniqueResultException` which is fine.

Naturally, I guessed that `Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR` would do the trick. However, it returns **exactly the same result** as when using `Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY`.

Code:

```
$ids   = [1, 2, 3];
$query = $this->entityManager->createQuery('
          SELECT item.templateId FROM MyBundle:Item item WHERE item.id IN (:ids)
    ')
    ->setParameter('ids', $ids)
;

// Regardles whether I use HYDRATE_SCALAR or HYDRATE_ARRAY
// $result is the same
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);
```

Here is how `$result` looks in both cases:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [templateId] => 52
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [templateId] => 90
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [templateId] => 89
        )
)
```

How I wish it looked:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 52

    [1] => 90

    [2] => 89
)
```

I know I can transform it into the form I want, but I wonder why `HYDRATE_SCALAR` isn't behaving as I expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

I think it behaves like this because, as [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) says :

> [it] can contain duplicate data.

That's when `array_column` (php 5.5) comes into play.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = $query->getResult(Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR);

return array_map('reset', $result);
```

There you go :)

Answer (score 0):

10 years later, I'm adding another answer, that I will hope is better.
Once again, [the documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#query-result-formats) I mentioned 10 years ago is helpful:

> - `Query#getArrayResult()`: Retrieves an array graph (a nested array) that is largely interchangeable with the object graph generated by `Query#getResult()` for read-only purposes. .. note:: An array graph can differ from the corresponding object graph in certain scenarios due to the difference of the identity semantics between arrays and objects.
> - `Query#getScalarResult()`: Retrieves a flat/rectangular result set of scalar values that can contain duplicate data. The pure/mixed distinction does not apply.

ORM means Object-relational mapper: it maps an RDBMS with an object graph. One one hand you have tabular data, on the other hand you have objects that can be related to each other.

When using `getArrayResult()`, you will get an array graph, meaning something (deeply) nested, like a JSON document.

When using `getScalarResult()`, there will be little to no intervention besides converting column names to field names, and that's why it can contain duplicate data. So for instance, If you write a query that retrieves a user with 2 phonenumbers, the former will give you something like

```
[0 => [
    'lastname' => 'Anderson',
    'firstname' => 'Thomas',
    'phoneNumbers' => [[
        'alias' => 'home',
        'number' => '0123456789',
    ], [
        'alias' => 'work',
        'number' => '987654321',
    ]],
]]
```

The latter will give you something flat and duplicated, like this:

```
[0 => [
    'lastname' => 'Anderson',
    'firstname' => 'Thomas',
    'alias' => 'work',
    'number' => '987654321',
    ],
],
1 => [
    'lastname' => 'Anderson',
    'firstname' => 'Thomas',
    'alias' => 'work',
    'number' => '987654321',
]]
```

Of course, if your query is simple enough, there is no difference.